# what is the difference between BlueGiga BLE113 and Nordic Semiconductors nRF51822

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I'm really struggling to find the difference between the BlueGiga's BLE113 and Nordic's Semiconductors nRF51822.

From specs, the nRF51822 is a `Bluetooth low energy and 2.4GHz proprietary multiprotocol Soc` which means that it supports both bluetooth and wireless protocols.

And of course the BLE113 is only a bluetooth chip.

I just cannot seem to be able to understand if there anything more to it, for instance, in power consumption which holds an advantage or as in tech, which one is better ?

Comment: No, this is not the right place to ask this, because it is about hardware.

Comment: sure, where can I ask this ? is there another subsite of stackexchange on this topics ?

Comment: @rolandjitsu: The best site for this question is probably [electronics.stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the "pleasure" of working with BlueGiga's BLE112 last year (2013). It's programmed in their own scripting language called BGScript, and the same is true for BLE113. BGScript was *horrible* for anything but simple "Hello world" apps.

It was severely limited back then (no way to group code like macros, functions or import, variables were always global) but it looks like BGScript has since gained new features which seem to make it useable now (I haven't actually tried the new version as I don't even have a BLE112 around any more).

There still doesn't seem to be a debugger, though.

**UPDATE:**

I've now also had the opportunity to look into the nRF51822.

It has a C API and is harder to set up than the BLE112, but way more powerful. The API documentation is OK: there is a public API documentation which sometimes could be more thorough, but there are also several examples. The code to set up a basic appliance is pretty straight forward. Nordic Semi has nice, long function and symbol names that make it easy to understand what's going on and, like I said, a lot of examples.

The "strangest" part is understanding what a so-called SoftDevice is and how it's used. Not a big deal. I've sometimes hit minor problems when the docs weren't enough. Luckily there's an active [forum from Nordic Semiconductor](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com) where often Nordic Semi Employees answer.

On-chip debugging works fine, but the Keil µVision IDE is... spartanic. I don't like it at all but that just might be a matter of taste. It works alright.

**UPDATE 2**

I was notified in the comments that BlueGiga since has updated BGScript. It now has a lot of features it was missing back when I was working with it. Thus the critique of BGScript now is different, the language itself isn't as big of a problem any more. As far as I can see, the pro and cons are:

*Pro:*

- Simple language that is simple to learn.
- Specifically tailored to write Bluetooth devices.

*Cons:*

- No debugger (at least I haven't found a word about one).
- It's yet another language you have to learn.
- It's still so simple that I wouldn't want to write a 10,000 line app with it. For example:

  - It doesn't have a modulus operator.
  - Floating point support is very simple and missing lots of stuff like `pow`, `round`, `ceil` or `floor`.
  - It's lacking useful support for string processing.
  - In general, is lacking a standard library.
  - You can work around some of these things by implementing them yourself if you need to, but you need to be aware that you might need to do so.
- In the *BGScript Scripting Language Developer Guide* dated February 16 2014 they write: *"BGScript has limited performance, which might prevent some applications to be implemented using BGscript."*
- You're tied to BlueGiga's compiler, so you cannot do (native) development on Mac or Linux and you cannot work around or fix any compiler bugs.

I think there's a C API now but I haven't found a PDF of its API yet (I don't have an account at BlueGiga any more).

**Conclusion:**

So all-in-all, I'd say go for BLE112 for simple appliances (where you absolutely know for sure it'll stay very simple) that can be implemented with the BGScript limitations. For everything that's more complex and you thus want the power of a real programming language (C), go for nRF51822.

Comment: I've read a bit about `BGScript`, but I didn't know it's so hard to develop with. For what I intend to use the ble113s it should not be that complicated. I only need the module to broadcast it's UUID and some other data that I've read it does without having to write any code, I'm going to use them as beacons basically.

Comment: For that BGScript is very likely going to suffice. In fact, if your device is this easy, BGScript might even be an advantage as it frees you from dealing with all the Bluetooth setup and stuff. IIRC, it's a config file and a script file, and that's all you need.

Comment: This has been helpful :) as a note, I intend to use CC Debugger from Texas Instruments, I hear it works well with the BLEs

Comment: An anonymous user added this as an edit: _The open source BGLib Arduino library may be useful_

Comment: Its really helpful description...

Comment: This comment is very biased, BGScript is just a very low-level language and should be seen more as something close to asm than something close to python or lua. Both chipsets are based on the TI CCsomething and can be programmed with the IAS suite (in C), but that is costy ($3000 for a license, w/o there's a size limit and you're pretty much screwed). The BGApi exposes all BGScript api commands over uart but then the module loses all "self control".

Comment: @S0lll0s: If it _was_ anything like ASM then there wouldn't be a problem. The total lack of any way to group functionality (macros or functions) or to spread functionality over multiple files simply make it _very_ hard to do any serious work with it and some things are impossible (due to copy&paste you'd go over the size limits). Show me **any** language with these limitations. At the time of me writing this answer, there was no C API and BGScript was the only way to program this chip (which otherwise looks very good). A C API would of course make a huge difference.

Comment: @S0lll0s: Also, as I said several times, if you only have a simple device in mind then BGScript may even be an advantage as simple devices are easy and fast to write with it. If it involves any logic or processing then BGScript is a severe problem.

Comment: @DarkDust the current BGScript version has `procedures` and multiple files via the `import` and `export` directives, read it up in the latest BGScript PDF!

Comment: @S0lll0s: Ah, now if you had given me _that_ information right away I would've updated my answer instead of adding those comments. I don't actively follow products I don't use any more, do you? Have updated my answer.

Comment: @DarkDust I'm sorry, After reading your post I wasn't sure myself anymore (I don't own a BLE chipsets yet, am about to order some) and had to read up again to be sure. Also no problem, I'm sorry if that sounded offensive or something, the exclamation mark wasn't meant as an read-up-before-answering but as check-it-out!

Comment: Now I actually have  question of my own: Do I need to purchase an additional license or something else to develop for the NordicSemi chipsets? The site doesn't really make it clear whether you need IAR *and* gcc or *either*. (and I'm on my mobile atm)

Comment: @S0lll0s: IIRC, IAR is the name of their IDE. I don't remember whether it was using GCC or Keil (commercial C compiler for embedded systems). So you will need IAR and which compiler it comes with isn't going to matter to you at first. I don't know about the licensing, I was not involved with that. It looks like you can simply create an account at BlueGiga and can request a 30 day evaluation license free of charge. Probably best to contact their support and ask.

Comment: No, I was asking about the Nordic Semiconductors nRF51822, I think the C IDE for the BLE113 (and the TI CC series for that matter) was this $3000 thing and it may have been IAR and I just falsely remembered it as IAS above

Comment: @S0lll0s Officially, Nordic support the Keil compiler. For application size less than 32kb, you can use it for free. You do not need to purchase any license of any sort and the SDK is open at http://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF51_SDK/.

Comment: @DarkDust so what's S110, S120 etc ? I didn't get what they are

Comment: Generally speaking I have had a really hard time finding modules to program and documentation etc and when I asked on electronics.stackexchange what module was good to buy the question was closed as off topic...

Comment: @Thomas I noticed the same problem (in the Bluegiga world), so I wrote several blog articles to help out: http://www.sureshjoshi.com/tag/ble/ and I'll shortly be working with the NRF51822 module and will hopefully be doing similar.

Comment: I am having issues setting the connection interval in nRF51822 to the lowest value possible (which is 7.5ms), the nRF51822 is not being able to keep this connection interval, with ble112 I have no issues regarding this